# Eclipse code formatter multiline function call closing bracket indention

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

Currently my eclipse formatter formats a multiline function call like this:

```
someObject.doSomething(
  some().long().chain().of().methods()
  );
```

But what I want is for eclipse to align the closing bracket with the method call:

```
someObject.doSomething(
  some().long().chain().of().methods()
);
```

I have tried playing around with new line and wrapping rules in the code formatter but haven't been able to achieve this. What would be the solution?

---

After some time of digging I found a similar question which has an accepted answer but seems not to answer the same question:
[Can the Eclipse formatter be configured to indent multiple lines between parenthesis properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186714/can-the-eclipse-formatter-be-configured-to-indent-multiple-lines-between-parenth)

The author of this question also states:

> Edit: I found the settings for "Line Wrapping" -> "Default indentation
>   for wrapped lines" and "Default indentation for array initializes" and
>   have set them to "1" instead of "0". That is better for the array
>   initializers, **but still doesn't indent closing parethesis to match the
>   opening parenthesis the way that I want it to**:

Comment: maybe in "Parentheses" -> "Method invocation"?

Answer (score 0):

The latest proposal on this does not take into account the closing `);`, but the first expression.
See Eclipse 4.23 (Q1 2022):

> ### [Method invocation wrapping indentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/jdt.php#formatter-wrap-invocation)
>
> It turns out it's not obvious how to indent a wrapped method invocation when the preceding expression itself is complex enough to also be wrapped into multiple lines.
>
> Should the indentation be added to the existing indentation at the end of the expression, or just reset and assume that only the indentation of expression's first line matters?
>
> Previously only the former behavior was available, now there's a setting to choose the latter.
>
> The checkbox called Indent from the base expression's first line is located in the `Line Wrapping > Wrapping settings > Function calls` section, right under the `Qualified invocations` setting.
>
> [image: Method invocation wrapping -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/images/formatter-invocation-wrapping.png]